# Is there a way to pass an ffmpeg command from a text file in Windows?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, cat, arguments

I was wondering if there was a way to pass one (or multiple) arguments from a text file for ffmpeg.

I tried a bit here with this in powershell (expecting it to work like linux but to no avail

```
ffmpeg -i file.ts $(cat command.txt)
```

And the output

```
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
```

I tried doing it in batch and nothing doing too

```
ffmpeg -i file.ts < command.txt)
```

I then get:

```
At least one output file must be specified
```

I'm stuck.

Comment: each shell has a different syntax. Why do you expect powershell to have the same syntax as bash?

Comment: Not possible. You can specify filters from text files. And you can run the entire command from a batch/shell script.

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to answer my own question. I figured it out:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %a in (`bat command.txt`) do ffmpeg -i file.ts %a
```

This basically makes bat (a Windows fork of cat) output the contents of the text file and then passes that argument over to ffmpeg to do its thing. [Credit @MichaelBurr for the assist in this other answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2768660/9878263)

Making batch scripts is hard!!

Comment: `bat (a Windows fork of cat)` what??? And batch script is really hard because of lots of legacy issues in it that can't be fixed. That's why new code should use powershell instead

Comment: in cmd use `type command.txt` for an equivalent of bash `cat command.txt`